# Как декомпилировать код android игры написанной на unity

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android, декомпиляция

Есть игра на unity, но в ней нет файла **/assets/bin/data/managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll** и других **dll**
 
Игра точно на unity потому что заставка unity и папка **/assets/bin/data/** есть.  
В папке managed только папки `etc, Resources, Metadata` а в `Resources` файл **unity_builtin_extra**  
В `/assets/bin/data/` файлы типа 
**2cce4b02b6fb1654c97c0a7766e7b47c** 
**441f5e3731f6e1d44b47d11bf0495a74.resource**, 
файл **boot.config**, 
файл **globalgamemanagers**, 
**globalgamemanagers.assets**, 
**level0-6**, 
**sharedassets0.assets.split0**,
 и похожие по названию, 
**unity default resources**.
Папка `lib` отдельно, находится в `/mnt/asec/имя_пакета/split_config.armeabi_v7.apk`
В `/data/data/имя_пакета`, `/sdcard/Android/data/имя_пакета/files` есть папки и  `il2cpp` и `Unity`
Файлы в `/assets/bin/data/` распаковываются с помощью unityex,
в них похоже только ресурсы.

Comment: Ну какие dll - это ж сборка для Андроида, а не для форточек. У Андрюши ядро Linux, библиотеки в основном **`.so`**, но для unix-систем расширение не главное, поэтому может быть и другое и вообще без расширения.

Comment: В этой игре используется Backend IL2CPP, это значит, что код грубо говоря транслирован из c# в c++ и скомпилирован с помощью компилятора в машинный код, это значит, что у вас не получится посмотреть код, можете использовать дизассемблер, но он в ваше случае можно сказать ничем не поможет.

Comment: @Aimon А в какой файл он компилируется, а то `Assembly-CSharp.dll` нет, и даже намека на dll в этой и других папках.

Comment: Путь к папке со скомпилированной библиотекой lib\пака в зависимости от архитектуры\ И там будет файл libil2cpp.so скриншот: https://imgur.com/04BjDKy

Comment: С помощью дизассемблера, но это вам особо ни чем не поможет потому-что с этого кода уже не получится получить c#, вот как выглядит ассемблер: https://imgur.com/iskRDHB, говоря простым языком вы уже не можете посмотреть код в этой игре на C#

Comment: Тут вам получилось восстановить иерархию методов, но их реализацию нет дело в том, что это тоже самое что декомпилировать какую нибудь программу на c++ для windows, то есть исходный код вы уже не получить на c++ не сможете а только код ассемблера

Comment: @Aimon то есть это их адреса в `libil2cpp.so`, получается их можно дизассемблировать и отредактировать инструкцию в hex редакторе по этому смещению?

Comment: Конечно, А что вам именно нужно изменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity может транслировать код из C# (посути сначала из C# в IL) в C++, файл называется `il2cpp.dll`, на android находится в папке `lib/{arch}/libil2cpp.so` в основном .apk файле или split-apk файле для текущей архитектуры

Comment: И что с ним надо делать?